# why isn't .htaccess redirecting requests on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, selinux, htaccess

A web app running on CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4 recently changed its domain name from `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com`.  The structure of the app at the `newdomain.com` is different than on the `olddomain.com`, so all requests from the `olddomain.com/anyurl` need to be redirected to the root url `newdomain.com`.

**A new `.htaccess` file was created, and `httpd` was restarted, so why do requests for `olddomain.com/testbadurl` fail to redirect to `newdomain.com`?**  Instead, the user just gets a 404 error at `olddomain.com/testbadurl`.

Here are the steps that were taken at the command line:

```
# nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

# sudo systemctl restart httpd
# cd /var/www/html

# nano /var/www/html/.htaccess

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com [R=301,L]

# systemctl restart httpd
```

Then the test user types `olddomain.com/testbadlink` in the web browser.  The logs at `nano /var/log/httpd/olddomain_com_requests.log` show a `404 error`.

---

**ANSWER:**

---

@garethTheRed got me thinking about `VirtualHost` directives in the `httpd` `conf` files, which ultimately led me to develop the following answer, which works and now solves the problem:

```
<VirtualHost www.olddomain.com:80>
    ServerName www.olddomain.com
    ServerAlias olddomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/olddomain_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/olddomain_com_requests.log combined
    RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that it is more secure to have the `httpd` `conf` files do this than to allow external access to an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`  that's not complete httpd configuration

Comment: Is there anything in the error logs that might be relevant?

Comment: As you're expecting olddomain to use `.htaccess` to redirect to new domain and it isn't, then I'd start by looking in the error log for olddomain. Hopefully, there will be something useful in there for us to work with.

Comment: Have a look in apache's main log: `/var/log/httpd/error.log`.

Comment: Are you tackling this problem the wrong way?  Shouldn't you just have the `<VirtualHost>` entry for `newdomain.com` have a `ProxyPass` that points to the Tomcat(?) server on the TCP port that's configured for `olddomain.com` (8011?).  Then use a Rewrite rule to simply remove the `anyurl` part?  I might have completely misunderstood your question, so please forgive me if I'm not making sense :-)

Comment: As you figured out the answer yourself, then maybe you should write your own answer to the question and let users who find it useful give you the credit. I won't be offended at all if you un-accept (is that a word?) my answer :-)

Comment: @garethTheRed Because I do not care about points. And because your contributions to this site transcend the point system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to put my head above the parapet with this answer - after all, an answer is deletable!

Apache processes it's modules in a not very well defined order. You can view the processing order by [enabling](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) the `mod_info` module.  On a Fedora 22 installation, this came up with the following (extact):

```
Post-Read Request: 
   -10 mod_http2.c 
   00 mod_headers.c 
   00 mod_remoteip.c 
   00 mod_proxy.c 
   10 mod_auth_digest.c 
   10 mod_http2.c 
   10 mod_reqtimeout.c 
   10 mod_setenvif.c 
   10 mod_unique_id.c 
Header Parse: 
   10 mod_setenvif.c 
HTTP Scheme: 
   30 http_core.c 
Default Port: 
   30 http_core.c 
Quick Handler: 
   00 mod_cache.c 
   00 mod_lua.c 
Translate Name: 
   -1 mod_lua.c 
   00 mod_rewrite.c 
   00 mod_proxy.c 
   00 mod_proxy_express.c 
   10 mod_alias.c 
   10 mod_userdir.c 
   10 mod_vhost_alias.c 
   10 mod_lua.c 
   21 mod_lua.c 
   30 core.c
```

You'll notice that `mod_proxy.c` is first in the list.

My (very limited) understanding is that your proxy settings will be processed first, at which point your WAR files are returned and therefore the rewrite never gets applied.

There are ways to proxy using just `mod_rewrite` and the `[P]` flag as explained in the apache documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html).  It may be useful in this scenario.

Comment: Your comments ultimately led me to the answer, which I added to the end of my OP.  I am marking yours as accepted because it led me ultimately to something that works.  Thank you and +1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable module "rewrite" to get .hatccess working:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service httpd restart
```

Comment: On CentoOS 7, you command gives `-bash: a2enmod: command not found`

Comment: @CodeMed Sorry, my bad! I'm a debian guy.